# Anonymous user name not shown on comments Drupal

Tags: drupal, comments

I am using Drupal 7 which has comments and blogs as core module. I have added inline comments module.

On my blogs view page when an anonymous user adds a comment, it allows to add their name but on save their name is visible(stored) as anonymous.

But on my node blogs page, if an anonymous user adds a comment, it also allows to add their name and save their name as whatever they have added and not as anonymous.

So, I want on my blogs view page also, when an anonymous user adds a comment, it should show their name instead of anonymous.

Comment: It would be helpful to see that code sections saving and displaying the name.

Comment: its coming from the module. for eg:  On <www.example.com> i can see Anonymous - 04 3, 2013 10:06
// my comment and on <www.example.com/content/post1> i can see   name - 04 3, 2013 10:06
// my comment